# How to specify enum in osgi blueprint xml?

Tags: osgi, blueprint-osgi

I m trying to use Dependency injection with OSGI blueprint.
I want to construct enum object/s by specifying it in XML DSL.

In Spring context XML this would look like -

```
 <bean id="MyTestEnum" class="com.foo.TestEnum"
        factory-method="valueOf">
        <constructor-arg>
            <value>TYPEA</value>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

How to achieve this in OSGI Blueprint XML file? I see the schema validation error at  tag..

Appreciate any pointers!

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try replacing the `constructor-arg` block with

```
 <argument value="TYPEA"/>
```